# remove "The" at the beginning of a character variable, and move it to the end

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have some data that looks like this (code to input data at the end):

```
Year    Movie
2012    The Avengers
2015    Furious 7    
2017    The Fate of the Furious
```

And my desired output is:

```
Year    Movie
2012    Avengers, The
2015    Furious 7
2017    Fate of the Furious, The
```

Should I be using `stringr` and `regex` formats? Is there a link you can recommend that explains `regex` a little more simply than most sites or help documentation?

This is pretty poor, but it was all I could do for now:

```
str_replace(df$Movie, pattern = "The", replacement = "")
```

Even just some hints of what commands to look for in the help documentation, or where to find explanations of what I should be looking for would be helpful.

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Year = c(2012L, 2015L, 2017L),
       Movie = c("The Avengers", "Furious 7", "The Fate of the Furious")
)

df

str_replace(df$Movie, pattern = "The", replacement = "")
```

Comment: Use a mere `sub("^(The)\\s+(.*)", "\\2, \\1", df$Movie)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sub("^([Tt]he?) (.*)", "\\2, \\1", df$Movie)
#[1] "Avengers, The"           
#[2] "Furious 7"               
#[3] "Fate of the Furious, The"
```

- `?`  - indicates that "The" is optional and will be matches at most once. Will also match if strings starts with "the". Thanks to @rawr!
- `.` - matches any character - zero or more times, which is what `*` indicates
- `()` - capture the text matched by the regex inside them into a numbered group that can be reused with a numbered backreference, i.e. `\\1` and `\\2`. See [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

I hope this makes some sence to you.

Comment: I think you mean something like `gsub("(^[Tt]he) (.*)", "\\2, \\1", df$Movie)`, your current version matches "T" or "the" not "The" or "the" and only says the e in "the" is optional

Comment: The additional explanation of the code is extremely helpful, and I would recommend to any people looking at this in the future to have a look a the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but this should work

```
#Get the index of the movie starting with "The"
inds <- grepl("^The", df$Movie)

#Remove "The" from the beginning of the sentence and paste it at the end.
df$Movie[inds] <- paste(sub("^The", "", df$Movie[inds]), "The")
df

#  Year                    Movie
#1 2012             Avengers The
#2 2015                Furious 7
#3 2017  Fate of the Furious The
```